# Can a logical expression be added to the objective function of a model in docplex?

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, cplex, docplex, cplex-python-api

I'm working on an optimization problem using Docplex and wonder if it's possible to incorporate a logical expression into the objective function of my model.

Specifically, I have three variables x, y, and z.

$$x_{ijk} \quad : \quad binary \quad variable$$
$$y_{ik} \quad and \quad z_{ik} \quad : \quad are \quad continuous \quad variables $$
And I want to model this objective function:

\begin{aligned}
 \min w_{1} \sum_{k \in K} \sum_{(i, j) \in V} c_{ijk}*x_{ijk} + w_{2}\sum_{k \in K} \sum_{(i, j) \in V} [(y_{jk} - y_{ik})*x_{ijk} \quad if \quad z_{ik} == 0]
\end{aligned}

Is it feasible to include such a logical expression directly within the objective function in CPLEX? If so, how can I go about implementing it effectively?

Comment: So you want to minimize $\sum_k\sum_{i,j} (y_{jk}-y_{ik})x_{ijk}(1-\delta_{ik})$ where $\delta_{ik}\in\{0,1\}$ and $z_{ik} \ge \epsilon \delta_{ik}$ ($z_{ik}=0 \implies \delta_{ik}=0$). This needs to be linearized.

Comment: What should the objective term be if $z_{ik}\neq 0?$

Comment: I have edited the question, it is just the second term of the objective function. In the model, the variable 'z' takes on discrete values from the set {0, 1, 2, 3}. When the value of 'z' is not equal to 0, the second term evaluates to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a "big M" approach, assuming that you can find a positive constant $M$ such that $\vert y_{jk}-y_{ik} \vert \le M$ for all $k\in K$ and $(i,j)\in V.$

Introduce new binary variables $u_{ik}$ and continuous variables $v_{ijk}.$ The second objective summand (the mess in brackets) becomes $v_{ijk}.$ Now add the following constraints:
$$3u_{ik} + z_{ik} \le 3\, (1)$$
$$u_{ik} + z_{ik} \ge 1 \, (2)$$
$$v_{ijk} \le M u_{ik}\, (3)$$
$$v_{ijk} \ge -M u_{ik}\, (3')$$
$$v_{ijk} \le M x_{ijk}\, (4)$$
$$v_{ijk} \ge -M x_{ijk}\, (4')$$
$$v_{ijk} \le y_{jk} - y_{ik} + M(2 - u_{ik} - x_{ijk}) \, (5)$$
and
$$v_{ijk} \ge y_{jk} - y_{ik} - M(2 - u_{ik} - x_{ijk}) \, (5')$$

Constraints (1) and (2) combine to set $u_{ik} =1$ if and only if $z_{ik} = 0.$ Constraints (3) and (3') say that the $(i,j,k)$ objective term is 0 if $u_{ik}=0$ (meaning $z_{ik} \in \lbrace 1,2,3 \rbrace$). Constraints (4) and (4') say that the objective term is 0 if $x_{ijk} =0.$ Finally, constraints (5) and (5') say that if $u_{ik}=1$ (meaning $z_{ik}=0$) and $x_{ijk}=1,$ then the objective term equals $y_{jk}-y_{ik}.$

**Addendum**: If the solver supports "if-then" (implication) constraints (CPLEX does), then the "big M" constraints can be replaced with implications, as follows.
$$u_{ik}=0 \implies v_{ijk}=0$$
$$x_{ijk}=0 \implies v_{ijk}=0$$
$$u_{ik} + x_{ijk} = 2  \implies v_{ijk} = y_{jk}-y_{ik}$$

As a general rule, you are probably better off with the "big M" constraints if you can find a reasonably tight value of $M.$

Comment: Thanks, the reasoning seems to be correct, Just finding the appropriate value of "M" isn't feasible. I just wondering taking into account that the second term will be calculated just in the case if there is an arc between (i,j) $$x_{ijk} =1 \quad and \quad z_{ik}=0$$ it s necessary to deal with the other cases.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "necessary to deal with the other cases".

Comment: I extended the answer to describe use of implication constraints if you can't find a good value for $M.$